# Trouble at differentiating a consumption function

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, aggregate-demand

everyone.

This is kind of a basic question, but I have a weak background on calculus and I already tried to figure this out by myself for a few hours without success. So, I am finally appealing on you - I even feel embarrassed about asking such a basic question among all of these complex questions in the forum.

Let's get to it: in the middle of a chapter about aggregate demand and IS curve in the textbook "Macroeconomia", by Mario Henrique Simonsen, there is the statement of this consumption function:

$(1)$ $C = aA + bY_d$   with $a>0$ and $b>0$

(C represents consumption, A represents non-human wealth and Yd represents disposable income)

Then, as keynesian theory takes A as given in the short-run (so it is treated as a constant), there is this differentiation of A in respect of t:

$(2)$ $\frac{dA}{dt} = Y_d - C = (1-b)Y_d - aA$

And there is my problem. Mathematically, I don't know how $\frac{dA}{dt} = Y_d - C$.

My train of thought is to differentiate the consumption function like this:

$\frac{dC}{dt} = a \frac{dA}{dt} + b \frac{dY_d}{dt}$

Then, as $\frac{dA}{dt} = 0$:

$0 = b \frac{dY_d}{dt} - \frac{dC}{dt}$

But it is pretty different than equation (2). What are my mistakes? Thank you.

Comment: $A$ is non-human wealth? Is it owned by lizardmen?

Comment: Well, at least in Blanchard's Macroeconomics, non-human wealth is the portion of wealth provided by someone's assets, such as financial assets. Human wealth is the portion provided by labor at present value after taxes. Therefore, I don't see any particular reason for sarcasm here.

Comment: I see, thanks! I guess I should have read more macro in English, I was unfamiliar with the terminology. Thanks agian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does not seem to have anything to do with calculus.

The idea is that the income not consumed $Y_d - C$ is saved (usually denoted by $S$).

This saving is then lent out to companies (via banks) who invest it (usually denoted by $I$), and the accumulated capital is used in production. I am guessing this is denoted by $A$?

And the change of $A$ in time is the investment (assuming there is no amortization).

Hence
$$
Y_d - C = S = I = \frac{dA}{dt}
$$

Comment: I thought that it was required some mathematical foundation behind the intuition that $A = Y_d - C$, but your logic seems right. I think I overthought about it and waste some time trying to face it with a calculus approach.